# Numeric or value error when assigning more than 32K string to a clob variable

Tags: string, oracle, plsql

I am getting the numberic or value error when I try to do the below. I am trying to assign 40000 length string to a clob variable, it should allow me right ?

I a loop if try to append chunks of string then there is no issue, but if I try to assign "more than 32K string" at one go then there is an error.

I have a requirement where I have to assign 32K+ string to a procedure with a clob input parameter.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

DECLARE

my_var CLOB;

BEGIN

my_var:=RPAD('*',40000,'*');

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUt_LINE(length(my_var));

EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUt_LINE(SQLCODE||' '||SQLERRM);

END;
```

Error:

> -6502 ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put yourself in the shoes of the PL/SQL runtime. It has to process the assignment

```
my_var := rpad('*', 40000, '*')
```

True, `my_var` was declared `clob`. How about the RHS though? First the RHS must be evaluated, and when the runtime does that, it has no way of knowing a `clob` is expected as the result. The first argument is `'*'`, which is `varchar2`, not `clob`. The return from `rpad`, then, is expected to be `varchar2`. This is why you get the error.

How do we fix this? Easily. You need to give the function a `clob` as the first argument. Like so:

```
my_var := rpad(to_clob('*'), 40000, '*')
```

Demo:

```
SQL> declare x clob; begin x := rpad(to_clob('*'), 40000, '*');
  2  dbms_output.put_line(length(x)); end;
  3  /

40000

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Good luck!

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the answer. I have one procedure which writes to clob column with clob as input parameter. As there is a limit of 32K for strings in plsql. Unix shell script will be calling this procedure via sqllpus and give the string parameter which can be "more than 32K". Like assigning this big string into a clob variable first and then passing this clob variable to the procedure. Is it possible?? Please help.